# Issues with MySQL query

Tags: sql, mysql

i have two tables 'reviews' and 'company'

//******Company******//

```
id | name      | others |
1  | company 1 | dhvhvbd|
2  | company 2 | didhhdi|
3  | company 3 | fyfyufu|
4  | company 4 | hdihdhi|
```

//*****Reviews******//

```
id | company_id | rate |
1  | 1          | 3    |
2  | 3          | 5    |
3  | 1          | 4    |
```

I am trying to write an SQL query like this (not correct but you should know what i want)

```
SELECT c.id
     , c.name
     , c.others
     , AVG(r.rate) rate
     , COUNT(*) count 
  FROM company c 
  LEFT 
  JOIN reviews r
    ON r.company_id = c.id
 GROUP 
    BY c.id;
```

This might look messy but this is what i want: to display all this listed company (irrespective of if they have a review in the review table), also get the average of 'reviews.rate' for each company (as they will be more than 1 review for one company) also get the count of the review where the company appears.

example:

display

```
id | name     | others | rate | count |
 1 | company 1| dhvhvbd| 3.5  | 2     |
 2 | company 2| didhhdi| NULL | NULL  |
 3 | company 3| fyfyufu| 5    | 1     |
 4 | company 4| hdihdhi| NULL | NULl  |
```

I hope its clear enough, i am just getting to learn some little bit complex queries

Comment: so... what is the issue with MySQL query? i mean, what is your question?

Comment: What you want all company or reviewed company list?

Comment: i want to write a query that will get me the result i stated as "display"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add all columns into the `group by` clause that won't get aggregated with a function

```
SELECT company.id, company.name, company.others, 
       AVG(reviews.rate) AS rate, 
       COUNT(reviews.id) AS `count` 
FROM company
LEFT JOIN reviews ON company.id = reviews.company_id 
GROUP BY company.id, company.name, company.others
```

And if you have 2 tables with the same column names then you need to name the table too. You used `group by id` in your query but the DB does not know which one to take - from `reviews` or from `company`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using aggregate operators like `COUNT` and `AVG`, you have to group your records, by `company.id`, `company.name` and `company.others` (all the columns included in the `SELECT` clause). For this reason your query won't work.

Furthermore, using `GROUP BY id` your MySQL engine will complain, because actually the column `id` is ambiguous, because both tables involved in the `LEFT JOIN` have an `id` column and the engine doesn't understand which column of which table you mean.

Use the following query:

```
SELECT company.id, company.name, company.others, 
       AVG(reviews.rate) AS rate, 
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(reviews.id) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE COUNT(reviews.id) END) AS `count` 
FROM Company
LEFT JOIN Reviews ON company.id = reviews.company_id 
GROUP BY company.id, company.name, company.others
```

See the SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/675e7/3).